# QTCreator copy files

Tags: linux, qt, installation

I try to copy the Target file, from creation directory to an own sub directory of my project. It looks like

```
Project/my.pro
Project/libs/mylib.so
Project/libs/mylibtool.so
Project/output
```

Now I added to my project file :

```
DISTDIR = $$PWD/output
MediaFiles.files += libs/mylib.so
MediaFiles.files += libs/mylibtool.so
MediaFiles.path = $$PWD/output  //Also tried $$DISTDIR
//MediaFiles.path = $$TARGET  //tried for build app
INSTALLS += MediaFiles
```

But nothing will reach my output directory.
What I do wrong?

I use QTCreator on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the files you can use `QMAKE_POST_LINK` variable which contains the command to execute after linking the TARGET together. So it is like:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cp $$PWD/libs/mylib.so $$PWD/output)
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cp $$PWD/libs/mylibtool.so $$PWD/output)
```

These will copy the files to `output`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the project file tells Creator where you would like installations to go...when you actually install. Did you add a "make install" command to your build steps?